# Close Parent Form from Child Form if user clicks on the "X" button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using WinForms. I have 2 forms, Form1 *(main form)* and Form2 *(Child Form)*. I want to close form1 when the user clicks on the "X" button up at the top of form2. In my code I'm trying to close form1 by saying `this.Owner.Close();` but it throws an error. Why is it throwing this error, and how can i close the main form from the child form when the user clicks on the "X" button at the top of the form.

**Error**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

[image]

**Form 1**

```
    private void btn_Open_Form2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.Owner = this;
        frm2.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

**Form2**

```
    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Owner.Close();
    }
```

Comment: `Application.Exit();`

Comment: You closed the owner.  Which will close its owned windows.  Which will raise the FormClosing event.  Which will close the owner.  Which will close its owned windows.  Which will raise the FormClosing event.  Which will close the owner.  Which will close its owned windows.  Which will raise the FormClosing event.  Which ... Kaboom.  Use a *bool* variable to break the recursion.  Or the FormClosed event.

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? This is not good UX.

Comment: @HansPassant i see... Is it better if i just use Application.Exit in FormClosing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call [`Close`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) method of the owner, it raise closing event handler of owned forms and this way the code makes a loop causing stack overflow. You need to correct the code this way:

```
void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CloseReason!= CloseReason.FormOwnerClosing)
        this.Owner.Close();
}
```

If you want to close the application after closing the owned form, you can call [`Application.Exit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.exit?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) methods:

```
Application.Exit()
```

Comment: Application.Exit() seems to be better if you need to tell the whole application to exit (which was what I needed in my case)

Answer (score 5):

You should remove `Form2` from owned forms of it's owner (i.e. Form1). Then you can close `Form1` without infinite loop

```
private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    var form1 = Owner;
    form1.RemoveOwnedForm(this);
    form1.Close();
}
```